# Zorin OS Lite compatibility with Acer DA220HQL

Tags: zorin

I have got an android PC (Acer DA220HQL) running Android 4.0.4 with the following [specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-da220hql-android-pc/) and i would like to ask you if Zorin OS lite (x86) would be suitable for it. Additionally if there is any installation procedure step by step to follow it successfully as many Google Android tablets are locked from installing other OS.

That would help me a lot!

Regards

Comment: @mods pls do not migrate. we already have that question remaining unanswered on android enthusiasts. question is especially about linux, not android https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_on_embedded_systems